# Empty is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm having some troubles to find what is wrong in my code to remove all the child of my list:

```js
document.getElementById('btnGetExistingFiles').onclick = function(){
var ul = document.getElementById('listExisting');
    //we split the files in a array
    var existingFiles = "a.yml b.yml c.yml d.yml".split(" ");

    //if the list already contains some values we remove them
    if(ul.hasChildNodes()){
      ul.empty();
    }

    //for each file we add an element in the list
    existingFiles.forEach(function(fileName) {
      console.log("add files");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.setAttribute("href", "#");
      a.setAttribute("class", "oneExistingFile");
      a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileName))
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
        <button id="btnGetExistingFiles" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="listExisting">
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and I don't know why my element has child despite it's an empty one at the beginning but anyway even if I do `ul.empty()` in the browser terminal when the list is full I have the error

Comment: Javascript does not have an `empty()` method. You're possibly getting confused with jQuery. If you are intending to use the jQuery method, then you need to convert `ul` to a jQuery object: `$(ul).empty();`

Comment: Why do you embed jquery but youre not using it?

Comment: In `JavaScript`, you should be using `ul.innerHTML = '';`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) is a jquery function .. I think you need to use `ul.innerHTML = '';` instead of `ul.empty()`

```js
document.getElementById('btnGetExistingFiles').onclick = function(){
var ul = document.getElementById('listExisting');
    //we split the files in a array
    var existingFiles = "a.yml b.yml c.yml d.yml".split(" ");

    //if the list already contains some values we remove them
    if(ul.hasChildNodes()){
      ul.innerHTML = '';
    }

    //for each file we add an element in the list
    existingFiles.forEach(function(fileName) {
      console.log("add files");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.setAttribute("href", "#");
      a.setAttribute("class", "oneExistingFile");
      a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileName))
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
        <button id="btnGetExistingFiles" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="listExisting">
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't get the element with JQuery, I'll fix it thank you for the answer

Comment: @Jerome You're welcome .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Theres no Element.prototype.empty property.
 But theres one in jquery:

```
$(ul).empty();
```